# Codeigniter Set a Cookie without a leading '.' on domain value

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, subdomain

I'm trying to integrate a new Codeigniter powered login area into a legacy (3rd party) PHP site hosted on a subdomain.

When I set a cookie named 'logged_in' in the CI area (intended to be used by both the CI section and the rest of the site), Codeigniter always adds a leading '.' to the *domain* value.

The problem being that the legacy site sets and deletes it's cookies for the domain '*dev.example.co.uk*'. The problem manifests itself upon logout via the legacy site, when it doesn't destroy the 'logged_in' cookie (presumably because it's set at a different domain).

I've tried changing the CI config settings from the default blank:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
```

to the actual domain:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "dev.example.co.uk";
```

or by explicitly setting it on creation with:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('logged_in', 'true', '86500', 'dev.example.co.uk');
```

or:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('logged_in', 'true', '86500');
```

But whenever I inspect the cookie in Chrome the Domain value always shows as '.dev.example.co.uk'.

I realise CI is adding the '.' for maximum compatibility with older browsers, (as stated [here at php.net/manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)) but for this specific (albeit unusual) scenario I need it without.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent CI from adding the leading '.' to the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesn't do that, it's either `setcookie()` itself or just your browser assuming the cookie domain as such. If you want to be sure which one of the two is - inspect the HTTP response headers and look at 'Set-Cookie'.

Update:

After looking at the [PHP source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/head.c#L76), I can surely say that it's just your browser displaying (or handling) the cookie that way.